# Destroy method makes the code unable to assign GameObject variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, gameobject

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class inventorySystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<itemInstance> inventory = new();
    public inventorySlot[]  slots;
    public GameObject inventory_panel;
    public GameObject player;

    public void AddItem( item _item )
    {
      itemInstance new_item = new itemInstance();

      new_item.source_prefab = _item.source_prefab;
      new_item.quantity = _item.quantity;
      new_item.item_name = _item.item_name;
      new_item.item_description = _item.item_description;
      new_item.stackable = _item.stackable;
      new_item.item_icon = _item.item_icon;

      
      inventory.Add(new_item);
      UpdateInventory();

      Destroy(_item.gameObject);
    }

    public void RemoveItem(itemInstance itemToRemove)
    {
      inventory.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }

    private void Start() {
        
      slots = inventory_panel.GetComponentsInChildren<inventorySlot>();
    }
    
    public void UpdateInventory() {

      for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
      {
        slots[i].AssignImage(inventory[i]);
      }

    }

}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
// itemInstance is the same just no inheritance

public class item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int quantity;
    public bool stackable;
    public string item_name;
    [TextArea] public string item_description;
    public Sprite item_icon;
    public GameObject source_prefab;
}
```

sourceprefab exist in both script as a variable. I have no access issues, no nullreferenceexpections, it just doesnt work. other variables such as itemname or itemdescription get the values as intented. the only variable that stays null is the sourceprefab. but if I dont call the Destroy method or delay it, it works. but I dont want to delay it because you know, it can cause performance issues or unpredictable behaviours

Comment: Can you show your `item` class?

Comment: I added it , hope its readable

Comment: why would you want to destroy the prefab it isnt real thats why you cant then make future things of it

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning `source_prefab` GameObject to the Prefab in your Project pane, not the Hierarchy Pane?

If it's becoming null when `Destroy` is called, it suggests you're assigning `source_prefab` to the instance of the Prefab instead of the Prefab itself found in your Assets folder in the Project pane.

Comment: I assigned it in the inspector then applied the overrides. when I enter the prefab I see its assigned. I assigned it from the assets folder.

Comment: when I assing it from the inspector it takes itself instead of the asset one. because they are the same. scriptable objects seem to be a good solution but it creates a lot of junk

Comment: Of course, you created prefab from object. In my opinion, the prefab is not instance, it is type like class definition. So I think it is impossible to destroy. If you create _item.gameobject from prefab, It is possible to destroy. Can you show me calling section for "Additem" function?

Comment: RaycastHit hit;
          if(Physics.Raycast( transform.position , transform.forward , out hit , 5))
          {
            if(hit.transform.tag == "collectable")
            {
              inventory.AddItem(hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<item>().item_instance);
              Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
          }

Comment: the gameobject is an prefab instance and has the item script. I assign the prefab in my assets folder to item.sourceprefab. but since the gameobject itself is an instance of prefab, it thinks the sourceprefab is this.gameobject. I dont know how to fix it